# Chat DB architecture: is it correct to create a table for each chat room history?

Tags: mysql, database, chat, database-administration

I develop chat engine with socket.io, Redis & MySQL.

Redis is for pub/sub and storing last 100 messages for each chat room.
Mysql is as storage of each chat room history.

More than 200k of chat rooms could be created by users.

Is it correct to create a InnoDB table for each chat room to keep history for fast access and best performance? Of course, tables should be distributed on a few shards.

Comment: Dynamically create tables isn't the usual practice. You'd better add a `roomId` column in your `message` table.

Comment: It's incredibly bad idea to create file per chat. You should never do such a thing.

Comment: @N.B. Dmitry said *table* per chat room, not file.

Comment: @dystroy Tables will created by daemon, which could pick a pack of 100/1000 messages from each chat and then write it to db. Is it bad idea? I think about your answer, but if we have 15k chats with 1000 messages inside of each, so we will have 15 000 000 rows in table.

Comment: There's no problem in having 15 M rows in one table. But you seem to be lightly going into a *very massive* chat system, not all chat servers handle 200K rooms...

Comment: @dystroy Surely the system will consist of a few app servers and a few to store messages.

Comment: @Mxx - what's the point of your comment? I struggle to see the point, it's obvious what I meant even with apparent mistake in expressing myself. Creating the same table (file) per chat is a mistake, from any point of view (which innodb will do if file per table option is turned on, hence the mistake, unrelated to actual question).

Answer (score 1):

Creating a table is very costly and slow. On MySQL this leads to file creations on disk and prevent space optimization.

Dynamically creating tables **isn't** the usual practice. I doubt MySQL would handle 200k tables in one database.

You'd better add a `roomId` column in your `message` table.

Comment: tables will created by daemon, which could pick a pack of 100/1000 messages from each chat and then write it to db. Is it bad idea?

I think about your answer, but if we have 15k chats with 1000 messages inside of each, so we will have 15 000 000 rows in table.